# Yet another regex for apache log files using PHP

Tags: php, regex, apache

I've read a dozen different responses for questions like this but all of them fail to me.

I do not know how to compose a regex (is out of my abilities) and I need some help.

I'm trying to parse an Apache log file (set as default, since I didn't make any changes on it - using *xampp*).

I've tried the following patterns but all of them miss some lines:

```
    $pat='/(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+) ([^\s]+) ([^\s]+) \[(\d+)\/(\w+)\/(\d+):(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2} ?[\+\-]?\d*)\] "(.*) (HTTP\/\d\.\d)" (\d+) (\d+) "([^"]*)" "([^"]*)"/';
    $pat="/^(\S+) (\S+) (\S+) \[([^:]+):(\d+:\d+:\d+) ([^\]]+)\] [\w.]+ \"(\S+) (.*?) (\S+)\" (\S+) (\S+) (\".*?\") (\".*?\")$/";
    $pat='/^(\S+) \S+ \S+ \[([^\]]+)\] "([A-Z]+)[^"]*" \d+ \d+ "[^"]*" "([^"]*)"$/m';
    $pat='/^(\S+) \S+ \S+ \[(.*?)\] "(\S+).*?" \d+ \d+ "(.*?)" "(.*?)"/';
    $pat='/^(\S+)\s \S+\s+ (?:\S+\s+)+ \[([^]]+)\]\s "(\S*)\s? (?:((?:[^"]*(?:\\")?)*)\s ([^"]*)"\s| ((?:[^"]*(?:\\")?)*)"\s) (\S+)\s (\S+)\s "((?:[^"]*(?:\\")?)*)"\s "(.*)"$/';

    preg_match($pat, $b, $m);
```

The first one is the best so far (113 misses on 1,000 records).

And here is a sample of a missing line:

```
10.21.142.253 - - [25/Oct/2014:07:42:36 -0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0"
```

It does work on lines like this:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Oct/2014:08:49:51 -0200] "GET /xampp/ HTTP/1.1" 401 1392 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0"
```

There seems to be something wrong on file size.

Comment: What lines do you want to get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is in just a hyphen `-` that you can add as an alternative `(\d+|-)`:

```
(\d+(?:\.\d+){3})\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+\[(\d+)\/(\w+)\/(\d+):(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\s?[+-]?\d*)\] "(.*?)\s+(HTTP\/\d\.\d)"\s+(\d+)\s*(\d+|-)\s+"([^"]*)"\s+"([^"]*)"
```

I also "converted" literal spaces to `\s+`. If you are not satisifed with that change, just use your original one with the alternation:

```
(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+) ([^\s]+) ([^\s]+) \[(\d+)\/(\w+)\/(\d+):(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2} ?[\+\-]?\d*)\] "(.*) (HTTP\/\d\.\d)" (\d+) (\d+|-) "([^"]*)" "([^"]*)
```

See [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/nD8rF6/1) and [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/nD8rF6/2)

Comment: It works fine. `$pat='/(\d+(?:\.\d+){3})\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+\[(\d+)\/(\w+)\/(\d+):(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\s?[+-]?\d*)\] "(.*?)\s+(HTTP\/\d\.\d)"\s+(\d+)\s*(\d+|-)\s+"([^"]*)"\s+"([^"]*)"/';` results in 100.000 reads and 0 fail. thank you.

Comment: Great. I think `\s` is really useful when it comes to longer regular expressions that need debugging or update. Also, instead of `[^\s]` it is also safer to use the `\S` (non-whitespace).